# error while creating a mapping for document type under an index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Hi I am trying to create document type "product" under an index "ecommerce" in elastic search using kibana console.

```
PUT /ecommerce
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "categories": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when i run this request i am getting the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product : {properties={quantity={type=integer}, price={type=double}, name={type=string}, description={type=string}, categories={type=nested, properties={name={type=string}}}, status={type=string}, tags={type=string}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product : {properties={quantity={type=integer}, price={type=double}, name={type=string}, description={type=string}, categories={type=nested, properties={name={type=string}}}, status={type=string}, tags={type=string}}}]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product : {properties={quantity={type=integer}, price={type=double}, name={type=string}, description={type=string}, categories={type=nested, properties={name={type=string}}}, status={type=string}, tags={type=string}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

any idea what is wrong with my the put request.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create types in ES post version 7.0 and that it has been deprecated. You have the below available info from this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

> Specifying types in requests is deprecated. For instance, indexing a
>   document no longer requires a document type. The new index APIs are
>   PUT {index}/_doc/{id} in case of explicit ids and POST {index}/_doc
>   for auto-generated ids. Note that in 7.0, _doc is a permanent part of
>   the path, and represents the endpoint name rather than the document
>   type.

I'd suggest to follow any of the approaches as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/removal-of-types.html#_alternatives_to_mapping_types)

Basically either create a ***new index*** for every document type or just add a ***new custom type*** field.

Below is how your mapping would be:

```
POST <your_new_index_name>
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "properties":{  
         "name":{  
            "type":"string"
         },
         "price":{  
            "type":"double"
         },
         "description":{  
            "type":"string"
         },
         "status":{  
            "type":"string"
         },
         "quantity":{  
            "type":"integer"
         },
         "categories":{  
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{  
               "name":{  
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         },
         "tags":{  
            "type":"string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Basically if you try to ingest any new documents, you would have to use the below endpoint:

```
PUT <your_new_index_name>/_doc/1
{
  "myfield":"myvalue"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which could also lead to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322613/elasticsearch-issue-types-removal/65418474#65418474

Spent some time realizing I misspelled the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I rewriter my query as following and it works .

```
PUT /ecommerce
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {

        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },

        "price": {
          "type": "double"
        },

        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },

        "status": {
          "type": "text"
        },

        "quantity": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "categories": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text"
        }

    }
  }
}
```